# Can I Pair my Existing Apple Watch (Series 2) with a New iPhone without "resetting" the Watch?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, apple-watch

My iPhone *died*; would not charge or turn on. 
I took it to Authorised Apple retailer (Not Apple Store) 
instead of fixing it, they replaced it with a new phone  
(_after a couple of weeks of waiting for them to get back to me ... 
meanwhile I kept using my Apple Watch (*Series 2 Model A1758 with OS 4.2.3*) but was using a "temporary Android phone" 
... the Watch has data I don't want to lose_)

So I now have a `new` iPhone and want to pair my `existing` Apple Watch 
while ***preserving*** all the health/fitness tracking data that the Watch has been accumulating.

> **Note**: I've done a bunch of searching to find out if this is *possible*,
>   but not found anything so far ...
>
> Also, I saw the *similar* question: [How do I pair the Apple Watch with another iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196314/how-do-i-pair-the-apple-watch-with-another-iphone) 
>   but it *assumes* access to the *original* iPhone to which the Watch is paired, which is sadly, *not* the case; the original iPhone is *gone*.

Comment: Are you restoring the new iPhone from the backup of your old iPhone?  Also, please [edit] your question to included the Watch model and OS version.

Comment: @fsb good call on including the Watch Model and OS version: Series 2 Model A1758 with OS 4.2.3 (question updated) thanks!

Comment: Do you have a backup of your data from the original iPhone?  Everything I'm reading says you'll need to wipe-out the Watch when you pair it with a new iPhone.  Restoring from backup will put your health data back on the device.